# IBM DB2 Connection error with autoReconnect

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, wildfly-8

I am using db2jcc4.jar version 4.19.26 and JDBC4 .

When I am adding **autoReconnect=true** in the connection URL ,

```
 <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/jdbc/Name" pool-name="Name" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
       <connection-url>jdbc:db2://host:port/db?autoReconnect=true</connection-url>
       <driver-class>com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver</driver-class>
      <driver>db2jcc4.jar</driver> ....
```

I am getting the following error :

```
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:347)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:354)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:288)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:1166)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:446)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getTransactionNewConnection(AbstractPool.java:541)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:442)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:379)
    ... 129 more
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.DisconnectNonTransientException: [jcc][t4][2034][11148][4.19.26] Execution failed due to a distribution protocol error that caused deallocation of the conversation.
A DRDA Data Stream Syntax Error was detected.  Reason: 0x2110. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=58009
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kd.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kd.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.y.j(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.z.bb(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.z.y(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.z.T(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.z.i(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.z.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.c(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:322)
    ... 136 more
```

Answer (score 0):

[IBM documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21598736) shows that the resolution to this issue is to use a different version of the JCC jar, hope that this works out for you. You could've at least added what version of DB you are using in the question. Please check this solution if it works for your situation!

The solution suggested in this documentation is to:

Use JCC driver version **4.11.77** and above or upgrade to **DB2 V9.5 FP7** or **DB2 V9.7 FP3a** and above.